# How to login with wget, cookies and csrf

Tags: shell-script, wget

Trying to troubleshoot my bash that scrapes this website daily. It used to work with wget and the following `postdata`: `pin=87654321&accessCode=1234&Submit=Submit` ... worked for a couple years then broke. I noticed they added a field to the post data that is called "_csrf", and on inspection it now sends `postdata` like this:

`_csrf=d3063789-88a2-4b50-ad38-5c34663797a0&pin=87654321&accessCode=1234&Submit=Submit`

So, adjusted script does the following.

1. wget index.html and save cookies
2. grep index.html for the csrf code
3. wget index.html to login using the cookies and csrf code and my password

But, my wget just returns the login page as if I didn't authenticate properly, so I'm still doing something wrong, not sure if it's cookies or csrf. What is it that a browser does when logging in, that my script is failing to do?

```
PATH_HERE="testxyz/"
MY_URL="https://csea.ehawaii.gov/iwa/index.html"
wget -q -P "$PATH_HERE" --save-cookies "$PATH_HERE"cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies "$MY_URL"
CSRFCODE=$(grep -o -P '(?<=_csrf\" value=\").*(?=\")' "$PATH_HERE"index.html)
POSTDATA='_csrf='"$CSRFCODE"'&pin=87654321&accessCode=1234&Submit=Submit'
rm "$PATH_HERE"index.html
wget -q -P "$PATH_HERE" --load-cookies "$PATH_HERE"cookies.txt --post-data $POSTDATA "$MY_URL"
```

Comment: Can you add what you are getting back as output and maybe an example of what you expect to get back as output?

Comment: Why not try the curl? https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: To debug this, enable developer tools in your browser, then take a look at the "network" tab. It will show you the requests and responses including headers and cookies, so you can emulate this (with wget, curl, or with the language of your choice). We cannot guess what happens at `csea.ehawaii.gov`, and we don't have credentials for it.

Answer (score -1):

CSRF token are hard to bypass. The point of having them is to prevent cross-site request forgery.

> A CSRF token is a unique, secret, unpredictable value that is
> generated by the server-side application and transmitted to the client
> in such a way that it is included in a subsequent HTTP request made by
> the client. When the later request is made, the server-side
> application validates that the request includes the expected token and
> rejects the request if the token is missing or invalid.

So using simple wget for this would be impossible. You'll need to rely on using other languages for this like Python, because it has libraries like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) . Using this, you can achieve what you wanted in the first place

Comment: I have written scripts with beautiful soup but why is it necessary. My browser is not doing anything complicated here, it reads the csrf code in the html, sends it back in the post-data with login info. Did the action of wgetting cause a new csrf to be generated?